# u-boot hangs on soft reboot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, u-boot

I'm having this subtle issue where if I put my ARM device (U-boot + Linux) under soft reboot cycle (stress test), it fails after 100+ cycles. The serial output I capture in failed scenario is:

```
 ...
 g_txrx_mode=1
 g_profileid=1
 id=0x1F11 board_type=0x0004 HAS_POE_SUPPORT=1
 Not POE
 read_rbf_header_from_ext4 - filename = e30.core.rbf filesize = 7317252
 cff_from_mmc_ext4:writing e30.core.rbf length 13 num_files 0
 Full Configuration Succeeded.
 crestron_load_rbf: use core e30.core.rbf length 13 rval 1
 Booting from primary
 Writing to MMC(0)... done
 dram_init: id 1f11 (id & 0x0001) 1 has_dsp/has_dante0
 DDRCAL: Success
 INFO  : Skip relocation as SDRAM is non secure memory
 Reserving 2048 Bytes for IRQ stack at: ffe2f708
 DRAM  : 512 MiB
```

On a successful reboot, next printed lines are:

```
WARNING: Caches not enabled
MMC:   In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
```

it seems it failed between 'skip_relocation()' and 'enable_caches()'. but why after 100+ attempts? Could it be memory issue? Memory timing issue? And how can I debug it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: it is hard to say anything, before you have localized a concrete place in code where does it fails

Comment: @AlexHoppus it fails in skip_relocation(). And I'm suspecting it fails at either one of following calls but not sure why: one copies global data to new allocated location (id), and other rebases the stack pointer:

          (1) memcpy(id, void *)gd, sizeof(gd_t);    // gd_t* id
          (2)asm volatile ("mov sp, %0" :   : "r" (gd->start_addr_sp) : "r0", "r1", "r2", "r3", "ip", "lr", "memory", "cc");

Comment: you may try use qemu for debugging (if your platform is supported), also you may update u-boot and check if the bug is reproduced on fresh version.  "but why after 100+ attempts?" it may be for example some uninitialized variable issue, which gives you a data abort only when a certain pattern in memory is created.